# Show database items as .html

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I Already know how to get data from the database etc. but 
i want my page url to be : "www.mysite.com/random/youritem.html"

i know i can't do query's in html, but i have seen alot site's displaying database stuff
with an html

how i do it now is like this: "www.mysite.com/game/games.php?id=5"
but it shoud be like "www.mysite.com/game/black-ops-2.html"

you don't see the php this way, i know this is possible because vbulletin works like this.
the forum post of vbulletin are editable but get showed as .html

Thanks for reading ! :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look into [mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html). You can use a [generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php) to better help you understand.

You'd want something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^game/([^/]*)$ /game/games.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But you'd have to test it out on your own to get what you'd like.